# why does GestureRecognizer not work on textview first time?

Tags: ios, gesture-recognition

I have a `textView` to input some `text` or `emotion`. so I make another button to change the keyboard to custom emotion view, and I also use `tap GestureRecognizer` for when I want to change back to `keyboard`. 
I found every time I need to touch the button twice, the `tap GestureRecognizer` can work well. I thought and search long time but no result, finally I fix it. I think some one will meet the same question, so I shared it below.

Answer (score 0):

because my add tap gesture recognition 's code is in init code, but when I tap textview, keyboard was pop up, the textview's position was changed too, so the init tap gesture recognition code isn't work now.

I fix it with add tap gesture recognition delay 0.3 s.